# Tiempo estimado con trafico

Tags: ios, swift

¿Hay forma de saber el tiempo estimado entre 2 CLLocations y que en ese cálculo se tenga en cuenta el tráfico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es posible pero con matices. No se puede configurar directamente el tema del tráfico, pero has de saber que siempre se hace el cálculo de la ruta en función de la condiciones actuales de la ruta, es decir, también se tiene en cuenta el tráfico en caso de estar disponible en esa zona.

Por ejemplo, para calcular la ruta entre dos puntos puedes hacerlo así:

```
let source = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.855990, longitude: 2.350923), addressDictionary: nil)
let destination = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.845572, longitude: 2.312584), addressDictionary: nil)

let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: source)
request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destination)
request.transportType = .Automobile

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in

    guard let res = response where res.routes.count != 0 else {

        // No hay rutas
        return
    }

    // Cogemos la primera ruta (por ejemplo) y mostramos los datos
    let ruta0 = res.routes.first
    print(ruta0?.distance) // Distancia en metros
    print(ruta0?.expectedTravelTime) // Tiempo en segundos

}
```

Con esto podrás conseguir los datos principales como son la distancia y el tiempo estimado de llegada para cada ruta que te devuelva.

Si quieres que te devuelva más de un ruta como alternativa, debes utilizar la siguiente propiedad:

```
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
```

Por otro lado, para acabar de mejorar el cálculo y dar la máxima información posible, puedes jugar con las propiedades `request.departureDate` y `request.arrivalDate` de manera que puedas conseguir el tiempo estimado en función de una hora concreta. Si los utilizas y la fecha de salida es a futuro (por ejemplo) tendrá en cuenta el tráfico "habitual" o estimado de esa ruta y podrás sacar rutas alternativas. Con la otra propiedad lo mismo, si configuras la hora de llegada, te dará la mejor hora de salida en función del tráfico habitual.

Por último, si con esto no es suficiente, utiliza [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) con el que podrás sacar toda esta información y más.